# Move moodle to subdomain

Tags: moodle

Hi i have moved my Moodle website from http://example.com to the subdomain http://subdomain.example.com. I have then changed in "config.php" the root url to the subdomain. The code is here:

```
$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://subdomain.example.com/';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/home/usernmae/public_html/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';
```

But I am getting *$CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, the directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.*

Comment: If you are using Cpanel to host manage your server and host your subdomains. You should know that a subdomain is considered separate from the root domain and it can't access its files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the `$CFG->dataroot` field, and provide an absolute path in your computer. For example:

$CFG->dataroot  = '/opt/moodledata';

The "moodledata" directory must exist and accessible to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

The dataroot may not be writable, Please enable logging and see the error logs.